# TextToColumns macro has no effect

Tags: excel, vba

Conside this Excel VBA macro:

```
Option Compare Text

Public Sub ColumnATextToColumns()

    Dim rng As range

    Set rng = Columns("A:A")

    Dim nrColumns As Integer
    nrColumns = CountCharacter(Cells(1, 1), "|") + 1

    Dim FieldInfoVal As Variant
    ReDim FieldInfoVal(1 To nrColumns)

    For i = 1 To nrColumns

        FieldInfoVal(i) = "Array(" & i & ", 2)"

    Next i

    rng.TextToColumns Destination:=range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="|", FieldInfo:=FieldInfoVal, _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub

Public Function CountCharacter(ByVal value As String, ByVal ch As String) As Integer

  Dim char As String
  Dim cnt As Integer

  cnt = 0

    For i = 1 To Len(value)
        char = Mid(value, i, 1)
        If char = ch Then cnt = cnt + 1
    Next i

  CountCharacter = cnt

End Function
```

It compiles and runs but nothing happens.
The macro without dynamic creation of the FieldInfo value does work:

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="|", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2), Array(5, _
        2), Array(6, 2), Array(7, 2), Array(8, 2), Array(9, 2), Array(10, 2), Array(11, 2), Array(12 _
        , 2), Array(13, 2), Array(14, 2), Array(15, 2), Array(16, 2)), TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
        True
```

Comment: Your FieldInfoVal is an array of strings, not an array of arrays, which is what is required. `FieldInfoVal(i) = Array( i, 2)`

Comment: You are right, it works.